# validate quiz result before saving to db

Tags: javascript, database

I'm developing a small quiz, where I validate the result before I save to the database in order to give the user a different status so they the ones answers all questions correctly gets a prize. Though I think I writing the logic bit wrong....
here is the part where I set user data into db

```
function setUserInfofunction(Email, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME,COMPANY ,PHONE, STATUS) {
    var result = WL.Server.invokeSQLStatement({
        preparedStatement: setUserInfo, parameters : [Email,FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, COMPANY,PHONE, STATUS]
    });
    return result;
```

and here is the part where I try to validate the answers

```
function validation(){

if (answers[0]==choices[0][0]  &&  answers[1]==choices[1][1]  &&         
answers[2]==choices[2][2] && answers[2] == choices[2][1] )
{
  setUserInfo = parameters (status = '1');
} 
else {
setUserInfo = parameters (status = '0');
}
}
if (answers[0]==choices[0][0]  ||  answers[1]==choices[1][1]  ||     
answers[2]==choices[2][2] || answers[2] == choices[2][1])
 {
  setUserInfo = parameters (status = '0');

  }
 else {
setUserInfo = parameters (status = '1'); 
 }
```

what am I doing wrong? any advice? Or is there any smarter way of doing it?

Comment: What is "parameters?" You're calling it like a function, passing in the "status" variable, which you are setting inline.

Comment: Additionally, are you setting setUserInfo to the result of the parameters function? I'm really unsure of what you're trying to do in the validation method, to be perfectly honest.

Comment: Lastly, what is the actual problem here? Is this throwing an error for you? Is it not producing the result you expected? Or are you just looking for a better implementation?

Comment: I expect the user to write the email,firstname,lastname...and so on, to be saved to the database, but I want to control the status, the full scenario is a user answer questions, type personal information, I validate the answers and save user information and status into database. I'm very new to javascript and not sure what I'm doing is correct

Comment: What is the purpose of the validation method specifically, though? It appears to be doing a big if on a bunch of conditions &&'d together, and then doing the exact same, except ||'d instead.